# How to access the user data in redirected page in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I have added facebook login button for my website. Code is given bellow,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Great Web page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });

        };

        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1" scope="user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,email"  on-login="top.location = 'http://localhost/index.php/';">Login with Facebook</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When the user click 'login with facebook' button, authentication window is displayed with extended permission. When the user allow to access the details, **user is directed to index.php file** using

```
on-login="top.location = 'http://localhost/index.php/';"
```

**Now I want to print all access allowed details such as user name,birthday,etc. in the index.php file**
Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Why are you redirecting the user after the login? Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: reason is that I need to get all details of the user to a separate page.Anyway to do this?

Comment: At least is there a way to get the details to the same page?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got this *on-login* attribute for the login button (I couldn't find it), but here's an example of how you can do what you want.
It's not tested, I just created this for you to get the point.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'MY_APP_ID',
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true,
        });
    };

     FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function (response) {
        if (response.status == "connected") {
            var userid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var signedRequest = response.authResponse.signedRequest;
            var expiresIn = response.authResponse.expiresIn;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

            // do something with the data.

            window.location = "index.php";
        }
     });

    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1" scope="user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,email">Login with Facebook</div>
```

You can read more about subscribing to events here: [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), and this thread you might find useful: [Get user basic information using facebook Login button plugin?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7131666/get-user-basic-information-using-facebook-login-button-plugin)